# Simple access to a sql .db3 file using .NET - how?

Tags: .net, sql

Lost in the talk of ADO, LinQ and System.Data.SQLite.

What's the easiest way of accessing (for read & write) a SQL (.db3) database file using .NET. Are we really talking about writing SQL queries or is there something higher level that is provided by MS or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go here:

https://system.data.sqlite.org

You will absolutely not find a better, more complete or more polished solution. And it's free, public domain source code too.

Comment: but does it still need to write SQL and do things with connection strings, DataAdapters and Datasets or is there a class based way now?

Comment: I don't think you understand your own question, or at the very least are not articulating it very well. If it helps, it is a full ADO.Net solution with support for everything from data readers to data adapters through to LINQ to Entities support. If that still doesn't answer your question, it sounds like you need to do a bit more learning on the topic of database access in .Net in general.

Comment: Re-reading my question I realize I wrote 'does it' when I meant 'do I'. Either way after reading some of the documents on LINQ and Entities with SQLite it seems like that's a good a way to go. Thanks for the pointers

Comment: @NathanRidley the link is broken, can you please re share a working link?

Comment: @WAQ Sorry for the slow reply, and thanks for pointing out the broken link. I haven't touched .NET or SQLite in years, but I'm pretty sure the link is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

System.Data.SQLite is the ADO.net adapter for SQLite (so those two are the same). LINQ2SQL is a data layer generator, but it only works for SQL Server.